# Call a ListView from void

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, void

I have a problem with a Flutter Code. I want to call the ListView aAntwort() from the void randAnswer(). The ListView should be shown as Text in the RaisedButton.
The Simulation show "NoSuchMethodError: The methode '_aAntwort()' was called on null. Receiver: null..... "

Can anyone help me?
Thank you :)

```
                                children: <Widget>[                     //StatefulWidget
                                  RaisedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      child:randAnswer()._aAntwort()),    //ERROR
                                ]

  



  void randAnswer() {                                                 //Random Answer 
    var list = <String>['aAnswer', 'bAnswer', 'cAnswer', 'dAnswer'];
    var rand = new Random();    
    //get the random string
    int i = rand.nextInt(list.length);
    String iAnswer = list[i];    
    //print the random String    
    print(iAnswer);

    //remove the random string
    list.removeAt(i);

    //print rest of the list
    print(list.toString());    
    //get the random string
    int ii = rand.nextInt(list.length);
    String iiAnswer = list[ii];    
    //print the random String    
    print(iiAnswer); 

    //remove the random string
    list.removeAt(ii);  

    //print rest of the list
    print(list.toString());    
    //get the random string
    int iii = rand.nextInt(list.length);
    String iiiAnswer = list[iii];    
    //print the random String    
    print(iiiAnswer); 

    //remove the random string
    list.removeAt(iii);

    //print rest of the list
    print(list.toString());    
    //get the random string
    int iiii = rand.nextInt(list.length);
    String iiiiAnswer = list[iiii];    
    //print the random String    
    print(iiiiAnswer);   

    //remove the random string
    list.removeAt(iiii); 

    //print rest of the list
    print(list.toString());




    ListView _aAntwort(){                   // I want to call this one
      if (iAnswer == "aAnswer") {
        return aAnswer();
      } else if (iAnswer == "bAnswer") {
        return bAnswer();
      } else if (iAnswer == "cAnswer") {
        return cAnswer();
      } else if (iAnswer == "dAnswer") {
        return dAnswer();    
    }

  }





  ListView aAnswer() {                    
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(this.todoList[position].aright,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  ListView bAnswer() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(this.todoList[position].bwrong,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  ListView cAnswer() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(this.todoList[position].cwrong,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  ListView dAnswer() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(this.todoList[position].dwrong,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returning value for a void function will always be null.

You can either edit the returning type of the the function

```
ListView randAnswer 
//or 
Widget randAnswer
```

and the last line should be `return _aAntwort()` to call the function, However I recommended you to separate `_aAntwort` function form `randAnswer` and use `iAnswer` as global variable since your are using it as a button call.